# how to create secure shared object (dynamic) library

Tags: unix, object, gcc, shared-libraries

I have two unix system, one public and one private system.  I would like to develop a function in private system and want to use in public system but I also want no one able to see or crack that function. What is the best way ?

Will a simple so file will solve the purpose ?

Thanks

Comment: "I also want no one able to see or crack that function" - resistance is futile

Comment: I think the answer will unfortunately be that this cannot really be done unless you are an expert code obfuscater and are writing the library in hand scrambled assembly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs to http://security.stackexchange.com